# Sending H264 streams to linphone through gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, linphone

I have an issue in sending `H264` streams to `linphone`.

When I play the following pipeline :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=C:/ test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc bitrate=192 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9078
```

Everything is ok and the video played in `linphone` screen.

But what I want to do is to save first the video streams into a file then send this file to the `linphone`. What I did is the following:

Saving into a file

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=C:/ test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc bitrate=192 ! filesink location=C: /videosample
```

Send to linphone:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=C: /videosample ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9078
```

The packets received but the `linphone` played a black screen.

I want to know what I am missing in my pipelines or if there is a specific parameter to set.

**Note** that it is working when a play a gst receiver :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=9078 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Comment: avdec_h264 ! h264parse ! x264enc bitrate=192  - try adding h264parse between those two and add a muxer before your filesink : ! x264enc bitrate=192 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=C: /videosample.mp4

Comment: @Samer Tufail , adding h264parse after avdec_h264 results in error " could not link avdec_h264-0 to h264parse0 " .. adding a muxer also after x264enc didn't work and the output in linphone still black screen.

Comment: add this before the decoder. h264parse -> avdec_h264 -> video/x-h264 ! x264enc .... remaining pipeline